# Update Previous iTunes Store/App Store Purchase without Active Apple ID?

Tags: macos, itunes, updates

I don't have an active Apple ID/iTunes account. How do I update software purchased in the past? How do I go down the "if you don't have an Apple ID" path below?

[image]

Mac OS X will allow one to bypass the Apple ID/iTunes account requirement. For example, iTunes was updated even without a valid Apple ID.

And what does an current Apple ID/iTunes account have to do with software and security updates for past purchases?

Comment: You can't. You can't download the content connected to an AppleID unless you log into said AppleID.

Comment: Thanks Ramhound. Why does Apple imply there's a choice? Why is getting bug fixes for defective purchases guarded behind a log-in? I don't want a new Apple ID because I'm concerned it will blow away my past purchases. +1 to Apple for another broken system.

Comment: How is it broken?  Every single digital account which allows you to purchase applications requires you to log into the account in order to authorize the device.  Recovery access to the account that purchased the applications in question.

Comment: When Apple suffered their data breach in 2012, they forced me to change a password. My second Mac Book (downlevel, for testing) was using the old password. So my account is locked out. Apple won't let me unlock the account with the new password. I went to the Apple store with a picture ID and bill with my address (which has not changed in 5 years), but I could not unlock the account. I ditched the account because it was not worth the aggravation of trying to unlock. All I want to do is update the existing (broken/defective/insecure) products they sold me.

Comment: "Every single digital account which allows you to purchase applications requires you to log into the account in order to authorize the device" - the devices are already authorized, and the purchases have already been made.